# Similarity score to compare all strings in column to first string using fuzzywuzzy

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, fuzzywuzzy

I have a dataset containing time-series of lists for a large number of objects (`unit`) and I need to compare, for each object, the lists to the first list for each object. To do so, I have been using `fuzzywuzzy` and its `similarity` method, but I don't really get the comparing all later instances (lists) with th first one for each object. To make this more understandable, let's look at what I have achieved so far. Note: I'm a total newbie at `fuzzywuzzy`.

My dataframe is of the form:

```
data = {'unit': {59: 'unit1',
  662: 'unit1',
  680: 'unit1',
  725: 'unit1',
  709: 'unit1',
  703: 'unit1',
  653: 'unit1',
  807: 'unit4',
  825: 'unit4',
  778: 'unit4',
  816: 'unit4',
  822: 'unit4',
  849: 'unit4',
  820: 'unit4',
  754: 'unit4',
  1031: 'unit3',
  1094: 'unit2',
  1008: 'unit2',
  1089: 'unit2',
  1044: 'unit5'},
 'Date_job': {59: datetime.date(2021, 6, 7),
  662: datetime.date(2021, 6, 14),
  680: datetime.date(2021, 7, 5),
  725: datetime.date(2021, 7, 26),
  709: datetime.date(2021, 8, 30),
  703: datetime.date(2021, 10, 11),
  653: datetime.date(2021, 10, 18),
  807: datetime.date(2021, 7, 19),
  825: datetime.date(2021, 7, 26),
  778: datetime.date(2021, 8, 23),
  816: datetime.date(2021, 8, 30),
  822: datetime.date(2021, 9, 6),
  849: datetime.date(2021, 9, 27),
  820: datetime.date(2021, 10, 4),
  754: datetime.date(2021, 10, 18),
  1031: datetime.date(2021, 9, 6),
  1094: datetime.date(2021, 7, 26),
  1008: datetime.date(2021, 8, 9),
  1089: datetime.date(2021, 10, 4),
  1044: datetime.date(2021, 6, 14)},
 'Vector': {59: ['A|14:1/9.0',
   'A|15:1/11.0',
   'A|16:1/12.0',
   'B|11:1/4.0',
   'B|2:1/3.0',
   'B|3:1/12.0',
   'B|4:1/12.0',
   'B|5:1/9.0',
   'B|6:1/5.0',
   'B|7:1/5.0'],
  662: ['A|14:1/9.0',
   'A|15:1/11.0',
   'A|16:1/12.0',
   'B|11:1/4.0',
   'B|3:1/12.0',
   'B|4:1/12.0',
   'B|5:1/9.0',
   'B|5:1/8.0',
   'B|6:1/5.0',
   'B|7:1/5.0'],
  680: ['A|14:1/9.0',
   'A|14:1/4.0',
   'A|15:1/11.0',
   'A|16:1/12.0',
   'B|11:1/4.0',
   'B|3:1/12.0',
   'B|4:1/12.0',
   'B|5:1/9.0',
   'B|6:1/5.0',
   'B|7:1/5.0'],
  725: ['A|14:1/9.0',
   'A|15:1/11.0',
   'A|16:1/12.0',
   'B|11:1/4.0',
   'B|2:1/3.0',
   'B|3:1/12.0',
   'B|4:1/12.0',
   'B|5:1/9.0',
   'B|6:1/5.0',
   'B|7:1/5.0'],
  709: ['A|14:1/9.0',
   'A|15:1/11.0',
   'A|16:1/12.0',
   'B|11:1/4.0',
   'B|2:1/3.0',
   'B|3:1/12.0',
   'B|4:1/12.0',
   'B|5:1/9.0',
   'B|6:1/5.0',
   'B|7:1/5.0'],
  703: ['A|14:1/9.0',
   'A|15:1/11.0',
   'A|16:1/12.0',
   'B|11:1/4.0',
   'B|2:1/4.0',
   'B|3:1/12.0',
   'B|4:1/12.0',
   'B|5:1/9.0',
   'B|6:1/6.0',
   'B|7:1/5.0'],
  653: ['A|14:1/9.0',
   'A|15:1/11.0',
   'A|16:1/12.0',
   'B|11:1/4.0',
   'B|2:1/4.0',
   'B|3:1/12.0',
   'B|4:1/12.0',
   'B|5:1/9.0',
   'B|6:1/6.0',
   'B|7:1/5.0'],
  807: ['A|10:1/13.0',
   'A|10:1/13.0',
   'A|3:1/6.0',
   'A|3:1/6.0',
   'A|4:1/2.0',
   'A|5:1/2.0',
   'A|6:1/5.0',
   'A|6:1/5.0',
   'A|7:1/10.0',
   'A|7:1/10.0'],
  825: ['A|10:1/13.0',
   'A|10:1/13.0',
   'A|3:1/6.0',
   'A|3:1/6.0',
   'A|5:1/2.0',
   'A|5:1/2.0',
   'A|6:1/5.0',
   'A|6:1/5.0',
   'A|7:1/10.0',
   'A|7:1/10.0'],
  778: ['A|10:1/13.0',
   'A|10:1/13.0',
   'A|3:1/6.0',
   'A|3:1/6.0',
   'A|5:1/2.0',
   'A|6:1/5.0',
   'A|6:1/5.0',
   'A|7:1/10.0',
   'A|7:1/10.0',
   'A|8:1/7.0'],
  816: ['A|10:1/13.0',
   'A|10:1/13.0',
   'A|3:1/6.0',
   'A|3:1/6.0',
   'A|5:1/2.0',
   'A|6:1/5.0',
   'A|6:1/4.0',
   'A|7:1/10.0',
   'A|7:1/10.0',
   'A|8:1/7.0'],
  822: ['A|10:1/13.0',
   'A|10:1/13.0',
   'A|3:1/6.0',
   'A|3:1/6.0',
   'A|5:1/2.0',
   'A|5:1/2.0',
   'A|6:1/5.0',
   'A|6:1/4.0',
   'A|7:1/10.0',
   'A|7:1/10.0'],
  849: ['A|10:1/13.0',
   'A|10:1/13.0',
   'A|3:1/6.0',
   'A|3:1/6.0',
   'A|5:1/3.0',
   'A|5:1/2.0',
   'A|6:1/5.0',
   'A|6:1/5.0',
   'A|7:1/10.0',
   'A|7:1/10.0'],
  820: ['A|10:1/13.0',
   'A|10:1/13.0',
   'A|3:1/6.0',
   'A|3:1/6.0',
   'A|5:1/5.0',
   'A|5:1/2.0',
   'A|6:1/5.0',
   'A|6:1/5.0',
   'A|7:1/10.0',
   'A|7:1/10.0'],
  754: ['A|10:1/13.0',
   'A|10:1/13.0',
   'A|3:1/6.0',
   'A|3:1/6.0',
   'A|5:1/3.0',
   'A|5:1/2.0',
   'A|6:1/5.0',
   'A|6:1/5.0',
   'A|7:1/10.0',
   'A|7:1/10.0'],
  1031: ['A|10:1/7.0',
   'A|12:1/2.0',
   'A|5:1/10.0',
   'A|5:1/2.0',
   'A|6:1/12.0',
   'A|6:1/11.0',
   'A|6:1/4.0',
   'A|7:1/9.0',
   'A|7:1/6.0',
   'A|9:1/2.0'],
  1094: ['A|10:1/7.0',
   'A|12:1/2.0',
   'A|5:1/9.0',
   'A|6:1/11.0',
   'A|6:1/4.0',
   'A|7:1/9.0',
   'A|7:1/4.0',
   'A|8:1/4.0',
   'A|8:1/3.0',
   'A|9:1/2.0'],
  1008: ['A|10:1/7.0',
   'A|12:1/2.0',
   'A|5:1/9.0',
   'A|5:1/4.0',
   'A|6:1/11.0',
   'A|6:1/4.0',
   'A|7:1/9.0',
   'A|7:1/9.0',
   'A|8:1/4.0',
   'A|9:1/2.0'],
  1089: ['A|10:1/7.0',
   'A|12:1/2.0',
   'A|5:1/9.0',
   'A|5:1/2.0',
   'A|6:1/11.0',
   'A|6:1/6.0',
   'A|7:1/9.0',
   'A|7:1/3.0',
   'A|8:1/4.0',
   'A|9:1/2.0'],
  1044: ['A|10:1/6.0',
   'A|10:1/6.0',
   'A|5:1/4.0',
   'A|5:1/4.0',
   'A|6:1/10.0',
   'A|6:1/9.0',
   'A|6:1/9.0',
   'A|7:1/8.0',
   'A|7:1/8.0',
   'A|8:1/3.0']}}
```

Since `fuzzywuzzy` doesn't accept lists as input, I need to transform the lists into strings:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['Vector_string'] = df['Vector'].astype(str)
```

which gives:

```
unit    Date_job                                                                                                                   Vector                                                                                                                                Vector_string
59    unit1  2021-06-07  [A|14:1/9.0, A|15:1/11.0, A|16:1/12.0, B|11:1/4.0, B|2:1/3.0, B|3:1/12.0, B|4:1/12.0, B|5:1/9.0, B|6:1/5.0, B|7:1/5.0]   ['A|14:1/9.0', 'A|15:1/11.0', 'A|16:1/12.0', 'B|11:1/4.0', 'B|2:1/3.0', 'B|3:1/12.0', 'B|4:1/12.0', 'B|5:1/9.0', 'B|6:1/5.0', 'B|7:1/5.0'] 
662   unit1  2021-06-14  [A|14:1/9.0, A|15:1/11.0, A|16:1/12.0, B|11:1/4.0, B|3:1/12.0, B|4:1/12.0, B|5:1/9.0, B|5:1/8.0, B|6:1/5.0, B|7:1/5.0]   ['A|14:1/9.0', 'A|15:1/11.0', 'A|16:1/12.0', 'B|11:1/4.0', 'B|3:1/12.0', 'B|4:1/12.0', 'B|5:1/9.0', 'B|5:1/8.0', 'B|6:1/5.0', 'B|7:1/5.0'] 
680   unit1  2021-07-05  [A|14:1/9.0, A|14:1/4.0, A|15:1/11.0, A|16:1/12.0, B|11:1/4.0, B|3:1/12.0, B|4:1/12.0, B|5:1/9.0, B|6:1/5.0, B|7:1/5.0]  ['A|14:1/9.0', 'A|14:1/4.0', 'A|15:1/11.0', 'A|16:1/12.0', 'B|11:1/4.0', 'B|3:1/12.0', 'B|4:1/12.0', 'B|5:1/9.0', 'B|6:1/5.0', 'B|7:1/5.0']
725   unit1  2021-07-26  [A|14:1/9.0, A|15:1/11.0, A|16:1/12.0, B|11:1/4.0, B|2:1/3.0, B|3:1/12.0, B|4:1/12.0, B|5:1/9.0, B|6:1/5.0, B|7:1/5.0]   ['A|14:1/9.0', 'A|15:1/11.0', 'A|16:1/12.0', 'B|11:1/4.0', 'B|2:1/3.0', 'B|3:1/12.0', 'B|4:1/12.0', 'B|5:1/9.0', 'B|6:1/5.0', 'B|7:1/5.0'] 
709   unit1  2021-08-30  [A|14:1/9.0, A|15:1/11.0, A|16:1/12.0, B|11:1/4.0, B|2:1/3.0, B|3:1/12.0, B|4:1/12.0, B|5:1/9.0, B|6:1/5.0, B|7:1/5.0]   ['A|14:1/9.0', 'A|15:1/11.0', 'A|16:1/12.0', 'B|11:1/4.0', 'B|2:1/3.0', 'B|3:1/12.0', 'B|4:1/12.0', 'B|5:1/9.0', 'B|6:1/5.0', 'B|7:1/5.0'] 
703   unit1  2021-10-11  [A|14:1/9.0, A|15:1/11.0, A|16:1/12.0, B|11:1/4.0, B|2:1/4.0, B|3:1/12.0, B|4:1/12.0, B|5:1/9.0, B|6:1/6.0, B|7:1/5.0]   ['A|14:1/9.0', 'A|15:1/11.0', 'A|16:1/12.0', 'B|11:1/4.0', 'B|2:1/4.0', 'B|3:1/12.0', 'B|4:1/12.0', 'B|5:1/9.0', 'B|6:1/6.0', 'B|7:1/5.0'] 
653   unit1  2021-10-18  [A|14:1/9.0, A|15:1/11.0, A|16:1/12.0, B|11:1/4.0, B|2:1/4.0, B|3:1/12.0, B|4:1/12.0, B|5:1/9.0, B|6:1/6.0, B|7:1/5.0]   ['A|14:1/9.0', 'A|15:1/11.0', 'A|16:1/12.0', 'B|11:1/4.0', 'B|2:1/4.0', 'B|3:1/12.0', 'B|4:1/12.0', 'B|5:1/9.0', 'B|6:1/6.0', 'B|7:1/5.0'] 
807   unit4  2021-07-19  [A|10:1/13.0, A|10:1/13.0, A|3:1/6.0, A|3:1/6.0, A|4:1/2.0, A|5:1/2.0, A|6:1/5.0, A|6:1/5.0, A|7:1/10.0, A|7:1/10.0]     ['A|10:1/13.0', 'A|10:1/13.0', 'A|3:1/6.0', 'A|3:1/6.0', 'A|4:1/2.0', 'A|5:1/2.0', 'A|6:1/5.0', 'A|6:1/5.0', 'A|7:1/10.0', 'A|7:1/10.0']   
825   unit4  2021-07-26  [A|10:1/13.0, A|10:1/13.0, A|3:1/6.0, A|3:1/6.0, A|5:1/2.0, A|5:1/2.0, A|6:1/5.0, A|6:1/5.0, A|7:1/10.0, A|7:1/10.0]     ['A|10:1/13.0', 'A|10:1/13.0', 'A|3:1/6.0', 'A|3:1/6.0', 'A|5:1/2.0', 'A|5:1/2.0', 'A|6:1/5.0', 'A|6:1/5.0', 'A|7:1/10.0', 'A|7:1/10.0']   
778   unit4  2021-08-23  [A|10:1/13.0, A|10:1/13.0, A|3:1/6.0, A|3:1/6.0, A|5:1/2.0, A|6:1/5.0, A|6:1/5.0, A|7:1/10.0, A|7:1/10.0, A|8:1/7.0]     ['A|10:1/13.0', 'A|10:1/13.0', 'A|3:1/6.0', 'A|3:1/6.0', 'A|5:1/2.0', 'A|6:1/5.0', 'A|6:1/5.0', 'A|7:1/10.0', 'A|7:1/10.0', 'A|8:1/7.0']   
816   unit4  2021-08-30  [A|10:1/13.0, A|10:1/13.0, A|3:1/6.0, A|3:1/6.0, A|5:1/2.0, A|6:1/5.0, A|6:1/4.0, A|7:1/10.0, A|7:1/10.0, A|8:1/7.0]     ['A|10:1/13.0', 'A|10:1/13.0', 'A|3:1/6.0', 'A|3:1/6.0', 'A|5:1/2.0', 'A|6:1/5.0', 'A|6:1/4.0', 'A|7:1/10.0', 'A|7:1/10.0', 'A|8:1/7.0']   
822   unit4  2021-09-06  [A|10:1/13.0, A|10:1/13.0, A|3:1/6.0, A|3:1/6.0, A|5:1/2.0, A|5:1/2.0, A|6:1/5.0, A|6:1/4.0, A|7:1/10.0, A|7:1/10.0]     ['A|10:1/13.0', 'A|10:1/13.0', 'A|3:1/6.0', 'A|3:1/6.0', 'A|5:1/2.0', 'A|5:1/2.0', 'A|6:1/5.0', 'A|6:1/4.0', 'A|7:1/10.0', 'A|7:1/10.0']   
849   unit4  2021-09-27  [A|10:1/13.0, A|10:1/13.0, A|3:1/6.0, A|3:1/6.0, A|5:1/3.0, A|5:1/2.0, A|6:1/5.0, A|6:1/5.0, A|7:1/10.0, A|7:1/10.0]     ['A|10:1/13.0', 'A|10:1/13.0', 'A|3:1/6.0', 'A|3:1/6.0', 'A|5:1/3.0', 'A|5:1/2.0', 'A|6:1/5.0', 'A|6:1/5.0', 'A|7:1/10.0', 'A|7:1/10.0']   
820   unit4  2021-10-04  [A|10:1/13.0, A|10:1/13.0, A|3:1/6.0, A|3:1/6.0, A|5:1/5.0, A|5:1/2.0, A|6:1/5.0, A|6:1/5.0, A|7:1/10.0, A|7:1/10.0]     ['A|10:1/13.0', 'A|10:1/13.0', 'A|3:1/6.0', 'A|3:1/6.0', 'A|5:1/5.0', 'A|5:1/2.0', 'A|6:1/5.0', 'A|6:1/5.0', 'A|7:1/10.0', 'A|7:1/10.0']   
754   unit4  2021-10-18  [A|10:1/13.0, A|10:1/13.0, A|3:1/6.0, A|3:1/6.0, A|5:1/3.0, A|5:1/2.0, A|6:1/5.0, A|6:1/5.0, A|7:1/10.0, A|7:1/10.0]     ['A|10:1/13.0', 'A|10:1/13.0', 'A|3:1/6.0', 'A|3:1/6.0', 'A|5:1/3.0', 'A|5:1/2.0', 'A|6:1/5.0', 'A|6:1/5.0', 'A|7:1/10.0', 'A|7:1/10.0']   
1031  unit3  2021-09-06  [A|10:1/7.0, A|12:1/2.0, A|5:1/10.0, A|5:1/2.0, A|6:1/12.0, A|6:1/11.0, A|6:1/4.0, A|7:1/9.0, A|7:1/6.0, A|9:1/2.0]      ['A|10:1/7.0', 'A|12:1/2.0', 'A|5:1/10.0', 'A|5:1/2.0', 'A|6:1/12.0', 'A|6:1/11.0', 'A|6:1/4.0', 'A|7:1/9.0', 'A|7:1/6.0', 'A|9:1/2.0']    
1094  unit2  2021-07-26  [A|10:1/7.0, A|12:1/2.0, A|5:1/9.0, A|6:1/11.0, A|6:1/4.0, A|7:1/9.0, A|7:1/4.0, A|8:1/4.0, A|8:1/3.0, A|9:1/2.0]        ['A|10:1/7.0', 'A|12:1/2.0', 'A|5:1/9.0', 'A|6:1/11.0', 'A|6:1/4.0', 'A|7:1/9.0', 'A|7:1/4.0', 'A|8:1/4.0', 'A|8:1/3.0', 'A|9:1/2.0']      
1008  unit2  2021-08-09  [A|10:1/7.0, A|12:1/2.0, A|5:1/9.0, A|5:1/4.0, A|6:1/11.0, A|6:1/4.0, A|7:1/9.0, A|7:1/9.0, A|8:1/4.0, A|9:1/2.0]        ['A|10:1/7.0', 'A|12:1/2.0', 'A|5:1/9.0', 'A|5:1/4.0', 'A|6:1/11.0', 'A|6:1/4.0', 'A|7:1/9.0', 'A|7:1/9.0', 'A|8:1/4.0', 'A|9:1/2.0']      
1089  unit2  2021-10-04  [A|10:1/7.0, A|12:1/2.0, A|5:1/9.0, A|5:1/2.0, A|6:1/11.0, A|6:1/6.0, A|7:1/9.0, A|7:1/3.0, A|8:1/4.0, A|9:1/2.0]        ['A|10:1/7.0', 'A|12:1/2.0', 'A|5:1/9.0', 'A|5:1/2.0', 'A|6:1/11.0', 'A|6:1/6.0', 'A|7:1/9.0', 'A|7:1/3.0', 'A|8:1/4.0', 'A|9:1/2.0']      
1044  unit5  2021-06-14  [A|10:1/6.0, A|10:1/6.0, A|5:1/4.0, A|5:1/4.0, A|6:1/10.0, A|6:1/9.0, A|6:1/9.0, A|7:1/8.0, A|7:1/8.0, A|8:1/3.0]        ['A|10:1/6.0', 'A|10:1/6.0', 'A|5:1/4.0', 'A|5:1/4.0', 'A|6:1/10.0', 'A|6:1/9.0', 'A|6:1/9.0', 'A|7:1/8.0', 'A|7:1/8.0', 'A|8:1/3.0']
```

Now, what I do to compare strings `Vector_string` instances with one another (for each unit) is the following:

```
from fuzzywuzzy import process, fuzz

UNITS = list(set(df.unit.unique()))
fre = []
for unit in UNITS:
    d = df[df['unit']==unit]
    d = d.reset_index()
    if len(d)>1:
        d2 = pd.DataFrame([process.extract(d['Vector_string'][i], d[~d.index.isin([i])]['Vector_string'], limit=1)[0] for i in range(len(d))],
                   index=d.index, columns=['match_Vector', 'match_percent', 'match_index'])
    else:
        0
    final = d.join(d2)
    fre.append(final)
    
dff = pd.concat(fre)

dff = dff.sort_values(['unit','Date_job'])
```

which returns:

```
index   unit    Date_job                                                                                                                   Vector                                                                                                                                Vector_string                                                                                                                                 match_Vector  match_percent  match_index
0  59     unit1  2021-06-07  [A|14:1/9.0, A|15:1/11.0, A|16:1/12.0, B|11:1/4.0, B|2:1/3.0, B|3:1/12.0, B|4:1/12.0, B|5:1/9.0, B|6:1/5.0, B|7:1/5.0]   ['A|14:1/9.0', 'A|15:1/11.0', 'A|16:1/12.0', 'B|11:1/4.0', 'B|2:1/3.0', 'B|3:1/12.0', 'B|4:1/12.0', 'B|5:1/9.0', 'B|6:1/5.0', 'B|7:1/5.0']   ['A|14:1/9.0', 'A|15:1/11.0', 'A|16:1/12.0', 'B|11:1/4.0', 'B|2:1/3.0', 'B|3:1/12.0', 'B|4:1/12.0', 'B|5:1/9.0', 'B|6:1/5.0', 'B|7:1/5.0']   100            3          
1  662    unit1  2021-06-14  [A|14:1/9.0, A|15:1/11.0, A|16:1/12.0, B|11:1/4.0, B|3:1/12.0, B|4:1/12.0, B|5:1/9.0, B|5:1/8.0, B|6:1/5.0, B|7:1/5.0]   ['A|14:1/9.0', 'A|15:1/11.0', 'A|16:1/12.0', 'B|11:1/4.0', 'B|3:1/12.0', 'B|4:1/12.0', 'B|5:1/9.0', 'B|5:1/8.0', 'B|6:1/5.0', 'B|7:1/5.0']   ['A|14:1/9.0', 'A|14:1/4.0', 'A|15:1/11.0', 'A|16:1/12.0', 'B|11:1/4.0', 'B|3:1/12.0', 'B|4:1/12.0', 'B|5:1/9.0', 'B|6:1/5.0', 'B|7:1/5.0']  95             2          
2  680    unit1  2021-07-05  [A|14:1/9.0, A|14:1/4.0, A|15:1/11.0, A|16:1/12.0, B|11:1/4.0, B|3:1/12.0, B|4:1/12.0, B|5:1/9.0, B|6:1/5.0, B|7:1/5.0]  ['A|14:1/9.0', 'A|14:1/4.0', 'A|15:1/11.0', 'A|16:1/12.0', 'B|11:1/4.0', 'B|3:1/12.0', 'B|4:1/12.0', 'B|5:1/9.0', 'B|6:1/5.0', 'B|7:1/5.0']  ['A|14:1/9.0', 'A|15:1/11.0', 'A|16:1/12.0', 'B|11:1/4.0', 'B|2:1/3.0', 'B|3:1/12.0', 'B|4:1/12.0', 'B|5:1/9.0', 'B|6:1/5.0', 'B|7:1/5.0']   95             0          
3  725    unit1  2021-07-26  [A|14:1/9.0, A|15:1/11.0, A|16:1/12.0, B|11:1/4.0, B|2:1/3.0, B|3:1/12.0, B|4:1/12.0, B|5:1/9.0, B|6:1/5.0, B|7:1/5.0]   ['A|14:1/9.0', 'A|15:1/11.0', 'A|16:1/12.0', 'B|11:1/4.0', 'B|2:1/3.0', 'B|3:1/12.0', 'B|4:1/12.0', 'B|5:1/9.0', 'B|6:1/5.0', 'B|7:1/5.0']   ['A|14:1/9.0', 'A|15:1/11.0', 'A|16:1/12.0', 'B|11:1/4.0', 'B|2:1/3.0', 'B|3:1/12.0', 'B|4:1/12.0', 'B|5:1/9.0', 'B|6:1/5.0', 'B|7:1/5.0']   100            0          
4  709    unit1  2021-08-30  [A|14:1/9.0, A|15:1/11.0, A|16:1/12.0, B|11:1/4.0, B|2:1/3.0, B|3:1/12.0, B|4:1/12.0, B|5:1/9.0, B|6:1/5.0, B|7:1/5.0]   ['A|14:1/9.0', 'A|15:1/11.0', 'A|16:1/12.0', 'B|11:1/4.0', 'B|2:1/3.0', 'B|3:1/12.0', 'B|4:1/12.0', 'B|5:1/9.0', 'B|6:1/5.0', 'B|7:1/5.0']   ['A|14:1/9.0', 'A|15:1/11.0', 'A|16:1/12.0', 'B|11:1/4.0', 'B|2:1/3.0', 'B|3:1/12.0', 'B|4:1/12.0', 'B|5:1/9.0', 'B|6:1/5.0', 'B|7:1/5.0']   100            0          
5  703    unit1  2021-10-11  [A|14:1/9.0, A|15:1/11.0, A|16:1/12.0, B|11:1/4.0, B|2:1/4.0, B|3:1/12.0, B|4:1/12.0, B|5:1/9.0, B|6:1/6.0, B|7:1/5.0]   ['A|14:1/9.0', 'A|15:1/11.0', 'A|16:1/12.0', 'B|11:1/4.0', 'B|2:1/4.0', 'B|3:1/12.0', 'B|4:1/12.0', 'B|5:1/9.0', 'B|6:1/6.0', 'B|7:1/5.0']   ['A|14:1/9.0', 'A|15:1/11.0', 'A|16:1/12.0', 'B|11:1/4.0', 'B|2:1/4.0', 'B|3:1/12.0', 'B|4:1/12.0', 'B|5:1/9.0', 'B|6:1/6.0', 'B|7:1/5.0']   100            6          
6  653    unit1  2021-10-18  [A|14:1/9.0, A|15:1/11.0, A|16:1/12.0, B|11:1/4.0, B|2:1/4.0, B|3:1/12.0, B|4:1/12.0, B|5:1/9.0, B|6:1/6.0, B|7:1/5.0]   ['A|14:1/9.0', 'A|15:1/11.0', 'A|16:1/12.0', 'B|11:1/4.0', 'B|2:1/4.0', 'B|3:1/12.0', 'B|4:1/12.0', 'B|5:1/9.0', 'B|6:1/6.0', 'B|7:1/5.0']   ['A|14:1/9.0', 'A|15:1/11.0', 'A|16:1/12.0', 'B|11:1/4.0', 'B|2:1/4.0', 'B|3:1/12.0', 'B|4:1/12.0', 'B|5:1/9.0', 'B|6:1/6.0', 'B|7:1/5.0']   100            5          
0  1094   unit2  2021-07-26  [A|10:1/7.0, A|12:1/2.0, A|5:1/9.0, A|6:1/11.0, A|6:1/4.0, A|7:1/9.0, A|7:1/4.0, A|8:1/4.0, A|8:1/3.0, A|9:1/2.0]        ['A|10:1/7.0', 'A|12:1/2.0', 'A|5:1/9.0', 'A|6:1/11.0', 'A|6:1/4.0', 'A|7:1/9.0', 'A|7:1/4.0', 'A|8:1/4.0', 'A|8:1/3.0', 'A|9:1/2.0']        ['A|10:1/7.0', 'A|12:1/2.0', 'A|5:1/9.0', 'A|5:1/4.0', 'A|6:1/11.0', 'A|6:1/4.0', 'A|7:1/9.0', 'A|7:1/9.0', 'A|8:1/4.0', 'A|9:1/2.0']        95             1          
1  1008   unit2  2021-08-09  [A|10:1/7.0, A|12:1/2.0, A|5:1/9.0, A|5:1/4.0, A|6:1/11.0, A|6:1/4.0, A|7:1/9.0, A|7:1/9.0, A|8:1/4.0, A|9:1/2.0]        ['A|10:1/7.0', 'A|12:1/2.0', 'A|5:1/9.0', 'A|5:1/4.0', 'A|6:1/11.0', 'A|6:1/4.0', 'A|7:1/9.0', 'A|7:1/9.0', 'A|8:1/4.0', 'A|9:1/2.0']        ['A|10:1/7.0', 'A|12:1/2.0', 'A|5:1/9.0', 'A|5:1/2.0', 'A|6:1/11.0', 'A|6:1/6.0', 'A|7:1/9.0', 'A|7:1/3.0', 'A|8:1/4.0', 'A|9:1/2.0']        98             2          
2  1089   unit2  2021-10-04  [A|10:1/7.0, A|12:1/2.0, A|5:1/9.0, A|5:1/2.0, A|6:1/11.0, A|6:1/6.0, A|7:1/9.0, A|7:1/3.0, A|8:1/4.0, A|9:1/2.0]        ['A|10:1/7.0', 'A|12:1/2.0', 'A|5:1/9.0', 'A|5:1/2.0', 'A|6:1/11.0', 'A|6:1/6.0', 'A|7:1/9.0', 'A|7:1/3.0', 'A|8:1/4.0', 'A|9:1/2.0']        ['A|10:1/7.0', 'A|12:1/2.0', 'A|5:1/9.0', 'A|5:1/4.0', 'A|6:1/11.0', 'A|6:1/4.0', 'A|7:1/9.0', 'A|7:1/9.0', 'A|8:1/4.0', 'A|9:1/2.0']        98             1          
0  1031   unit3  2021-09-06  [A|10:1/7.0, A|12:1/2.0, A|5:1/10.0, A|5:1/2.0, A|6:1/12.0, A|6:1/11.0, A|6:1/4.0, A|7:1/9.0, A|7:1/6.0, A|9:1/2.0]      ['A|10:1/7.0', 'A|12:1/2.0', 'A|5:1/10.0', 'A|5:1/2.0', 'A|6:1/12.0', 'A|6:1/11.0', 'A|6:1/4.0', 'A|7:1/9.0', 'A|7:1/6.0', 'A|9:1/2.0']      ['A|10:1/13.0', 'A|10:1/13.0', 'A|3:1/6.0', 'A|3:1/6.0', 'A|5:1/2.0', 'A|5:1/2.0', 'A|6:1/5.0', 'A|6:1/5.0', 'A|7:1/10.0', 'A|7:1/10.0']     99             1          
0  807    unit4  2021-07-19  [A|10:1/13.0, A|10:1/13.0, A|3:1/6.0, A|3:1/6.0, A|4:1/2.0, A|5:1/2.0, A|6:1/5.0, A|6:1/5.0, A|7:1/10.0, A|7:1/10.0]     ['A|10:1/13.0', 'A|10:1/13.0', 'A|3:1/6.0', 'A|3:1/6.0', 'A|4:1/2.0', 'A|5:1/2.0', 'A|6:1/5.0', 'A|6:1/5.0', 'A|7:1/10.0', 'A|7:1/10.0']     ['A|10:1/13.0', 'A|10:1/13.0', 'A|3:1/6.0', 'A|3:1/6.0', 'A|5:1/2.0', 'A|5:1/2.0', 'A|6:1/5.0', 'A|6:1/5.0', 'A|7:1/10.0', 'A|7:1/10.0']     99             1          
1  825    unit4  2021-07-26  [A|10:1/13.0, A|10:1/13.0, A|3:1/6.0, A|3:1/6.0, A|5:1/2.0, A|5:1/2.0, A|6:1/5.0, A|6:1/5.0, A|7:1/10.0, A|7:1/10.0]     ['A|10:1/13.0', 'A|10:1/13.0', 'A|3:1/6.0', 'A|3:1/6.0', 'A|5:1/2.0', 'A|5:1/2.0', 'A|6:1/5.0', 'A|6:1/5.0', 'A|7:1/10.0', 'A|7:1/10.0']     ['A|10:1/13.0', 'A|10:1/13.0', 'A|3:1/6.0', 'A|3:1/6.0', 'A|4:1/2.0', 'A|5:1/2.0', 'A|6:1/5.0', 'A|6:1/5.0', 'A|7:1/10.0', 'A|7:1/10.0']     99             0          
2  778    unit4  2021-08-23  [A|10:1/13.0, A|10:1/13.0, A|3:1/6.0, A|3:1/6.0, A|5:1/2.0, A|6:1/5.0, A|6:1/5.0, A|7:1/10.0, A|7:1/10.0, A|8:1/7.0]     ['A|10:1/13.0', 'A|10:1/13.0', 'A|3:1/6.0', 'A|3:1/6.0', 'A|5:1/2.0', 'A|6:1/5.0', 'A|6:1/5.0', 'A|7:1/10.0', 'A|7:1/10.0', 'A|8:1/7.0']     ['A|10:1/13.0', 'A|10:1/13.0', 'A|3:1/6.0', 'A|3:1/6.0', 'A|5:1/2.0', 'A|6:1/5.0', 'A|6:1/4.0', 'A|7:1/10.0', 'A|7:1/10.0', 'A|8:1/7.0']     99             3          
3  816    unit4  2021-08-30  [A|10:1/13.0, A|10:1/13.0, A|3:1/6.0, A|3:1/6.0, A|5:1/2.0, A|6:1/5.0, A|6:1/4.0, A|7:1/10.0, A|7:1/10.0, A|8:1/7.0]     ['A|10:1/13.0', 'A|10:1/13.0', 'A|3:1/6.0', 'A|3:1/6.0', 'A|5:1/2.0', 'A|6:1/5.0', 'A|6:1/4.0', 'A|7:1/10.0', 'A|7:1/10.0', 'A|8:1/7.0']     ['A|10:1/13.0', 'A|10:1/13.0', 'A|3:1/6.0', 'A|3:1/6.0', 'A|5:1/2.0', 'A|6:1/5.0', 'A|6:1/5.0', 'A|7:1/10.0', 'A|7:1/10.0', 'A|8:1/7.0']     99             2          
4  822    unit4  2021-09-06  [A|10:1/13.0, A|10:1/13.0, A|3:1/6.0, A|3:1/6.0, A|5:1/2.0, A|5:1/2.0, A|6:1/5.0, A|6:1/4.0, A|7:1/10.0, A|7:1/10.0]     ['A|10:1/13.0', 'A|10:1/13.0', 'A|3:1/6.0', 'A|3:1/6.0', 'A|5:1/2.0', 'A|5:1/2.0', 'A|6:1/5.0', 'A|6:1/4.0', 'A|7:1/10.0', 'A|7:1/10.0']     ['A|10:1/13.0', 'A|10:1/13.0', 'A|3:1/6.0', 'A|3:1/6.0', 'A|5:1/2.0', 'A|5:1/2.0', 'A|6:1/5.0', 'A|6:1/5.0', 'A|7:1/10.0', 'A|7:1/10.0']     99             1          
5  849    unit4  2021-09-27  [A|10:1/13.0, A|10:1/13.0, A|3:1/6.0, A|3:1/6.0, A|5:1/3.0, A|5:1/2.0, A|6:1/5.0, A|6:1/5.0, A|7:1/10.0, A|7:1/10.0]     ['A|10:1/13.0', 'A|10:1/13.0', 'A|3:1/6.0', 'A|3:1/6.0', 'A|5:1/3.0', 'A|5:1/2.0', 'A|6:1/5.0', 'A|6:1/5.0', 'A|7:1/10.0', 'A|7:1/10.0']     ['A|10:1/13.0', 'A|10:1/13.0', 'A|3:1/6.0', 'A|3:1/6.0', 'A|5:1/3.0', 'A|5:1/2.0', 'A|6:1/5.0', 'A|6:1/5.0', 'A|7:1/10.0', 'A|7:1/10.0']     100            7          
6  820    unit4  2021-10-04  [A|10:1/13.0, A|10:1/13.0, A|3:1/6.0, A|3:1/6.0, A|5:1/5.0, A|5:1/2.0, A|6:1/5.0, A|6:1/5.0, A|7:1/10.0, A|7:1/10.0]     ['A|10:1/13.0', 'A|10:1/13.0', 'A|3:1/6.0', 'A|3:1/6.0', 'A|5:1/5.0', 'A|5:1/2.0', 'A|6:1/5.0', 'A|6:1/5.0', 'A|7:1/10.0', 'A|7:1/10.0']     ['A|10:1/13.0', 'A|10:1/13.0', 'A|3:1/6.0', 'A|3:1/6.0', 'A|5:1/2.0', 'A|5:1/2.0', 'A|6:1/5.0', 'A|6:1/5.0', 'A|7:1/10.0', 'A|7:1/10.0']     99             1          
7  754    unit4  2021-10-18  [A|10:1/13.0, A|10:1/13.0, A|3:1/6.0, A|3:1/6.0, A|5:1/3.0, A|5:1/2.0, A|6:1/5.0, A|6:1/5.0, A|7:1/10.0, A|7:1/10.0]     ['A|10:1/13.0', 'A|10:1/13.0', 'A|3:1/6.0', 'A|3:1/6.0', 'A|5:1/3.0', 'A|5:1/2.0', 'A|6:1/5.0', 'A|6:1/5.0', 'A|7:1/10.0', 'A|7:1/10.0']     ['A|10:1/13.0', 'A|10:1/13.0', 'A|3:1/6.0', 'A|3:1/6.0', 'A|5:1/3.0', 'A|5:1/2.0', 'A|6:1/5.0', 'A|6:1/5.0', 'A|7:1/10.0', 'A|7:1/10.0']     100            5          
0  1044   unit5  2021-06-14  [A|10:1/6.0, A|10:1/6.0, A|5:1/4.0, A|5:1/4.0, A|6:1/10.0, A|6:1/9.0, A|6:1/9.0, A|7:1/8.0, A|7:1/8.0, A|8:1/3.0]        ['A|10:1/6.0', 'A|10:1/6.0', 'A|5:1/4.0', 'A|5:1/4.0', 'A|6:1/10.0', 'A|6:1/9.0', 'A|6:1/9.0', 'A|7:1/8.0', 'A|7:1/8.0', 'A|8:1/3.0']        ['A|10:1/7.0', 'A|12:1/2.0', 'A|5:1/9.0', 'A|5:1/4.0', 'A|6:1/11.0', 'A|6:1/4.0', 'A|7:1/9.0', 'A|7:1/9.0', 'A|8:1/4.0', 'A|9:1/2.0']        95             1
```

Note that I have created

a) A column giving a percentage of match with another string

AND

b) the index of the row which matches a string. But this is not really what I want. Indeed, I want the first row of each group to have 100% match with itself and `match_index = 0` and that the other string are compared to that first string.

Another method that I am ok with is the following:

```
fred = []
for unit in UNITS:
    d = df[df['unit']==unit]
    d = d.reset_index()
   
    score_sort = [(x,) + i
             for x in d['Vector_string'] 
             for i in process.extract(x, d['Vector_string'],scorer=fuzz.token_sort_ratio)]
 
    similarity_sort = pd.DataFrame(score_sort, columns=['Vector_string_r','Matched_vector','match_sort','score_sort'])
   
    final = d.join(similarity_sort)
    

    fred.append(final)
    
dfff = pd.concat(fred)
```

which gives:

```
print(dfff.sort_values(['unit','Date_job']).head(10))

index   unit    Date_job                                                                                                                   Vector                                                                                                                                Vector_string                                                                                                                             Vector_string_r                                                                                                                              Matched_vector  match_sort  score_sort
0  59     unit1  2021-06-07  [A|14:1/9.0, A|15:1/11.0, A|16:1/12.0, B|11:1/4.0, B|2:1/3.0, B|3:1/12.0, B|4:1/12.0, B|5:1/9.0, B|6:1/5.0, B|7:1/5.0]   ['A|14:1/9.0', 'A|15:1/11.0', 'A|16:1/12.0', 'B|11:1/4.0', 'B|2:1/3.0', 'B|3:1/12.0', 'B|4:1/12.0', 'B|5:1/9.0', 'B|6:1/5.0', 'B|7:1/5.0']   ['A|14:1/9.0', 'A|15:1/11.0', 'A|16:1/12.0', 'B|11:1/4.0', 'B|2:1/3.0', 'B|3:1/12.0', 'B|4:1/12.0', 'B|5:1/9.0', 'B|6:1/5.0', 'B|7:1/5.0']  ['A|14:1/9.0', 'A|15:1/11.0', 'A|16:1/12.0', 'B|11:1/4.0', 'B|2:1/3.0', 'B|3:1/12.0', 'B|4:1/12.0', 'B|5:1/9.0', 'B|6:1/5.0', 'B|7:1/5.0']  100         0         
1  662    unit1  2021-06-14  [A|14:1/9.0, A|15:1/11.0, A|16:1/12.0, B|11:1/4.0, B|3:1/12.0, B|4:1/12.0, B|5:1/9.0, B|5:1/8.0, B|6:1/5.0, B|7:1/5.0]   ['A|14:1/9.0', 'A|15:1/11.0', 'A|16:1/12.0', 'B|11:1/4.0', 'B|3:1/12.0', 'B|4:1/12.0', 'B|5:1/9.0', 'B|5:1/8.0', 'B|6:1/5.0', 'B|7:1/5.0']   ['A|14:1/9.0', 'A|15:1/11.0', 'A|16:1/12.0', 'B|11:1/4.0', 'B|2:1/3.0', 'B|3:1/12.0', 'B|4:1/12.0', 'B|5:1/9.0', 'B|6:1/5.0', 'B|7:1/5.0']  ['A|14:1/9.0', 'A|15:1/11.0', 'A|16:1/12.0', 'B|11:1/4.0', 'B|2:1/3.0', 'B|3:1/12.0', 'B|4:1/12.0', 'B|5:1/9.0', 'B|6:1/5.0', 'B|7:1/5.0']  100         3         
2  680    unit1  2021-07-05  [A|14:1/9.0, A|14:1/4.0, A|15:1/11.0, A|16:1/12.0, B|11:1/4.0, B|3:1/12.0, B|4:1/12.0, B|5:1/9.0, B|6:1/5.0, B|7:1/5.0]  ['A|14:1/9.0', 'A|14:1/4.0', 'A|15:1/11.0', 'A|16:1/12.0', 'B|11:1/4.0', 'B|3:1/12.0', 'B|4:1/12.0', 'B|5:1/9.0', 'B|6:1/5.0', 'B|7:1/5.0']  ['A|14:1/9.0', 'A|15:1/11.0', 'A|16:1/12.0', 'B|11:1/4.0', 'B|2:1/3.0', 'B|3:1/12.0', 'B|4:1/12.0', 'B|5:1/9.0', 'B|6:1/5.0', 'B|7:1/5.0']  ['A|14:1/9.0', 'A|15:1/11.0', 'A|16:1/12.0', 'B|11:1/4.0', 'B|2:1/3.0', 'B|3:1/12.0', 'B|4:1/12.0', 'B|5:1/9.0', 'B|6:1/5.0', 'B|7:1/5.0']  100         4         
3  725    unit1  2021-07-26  [A|14:1/9.0, A|15:1/11.0, A|16:1/12.0, B|11:1/4.0, B|2:1/3.0, B|3:1/12.0, B|4:1/12.0, B|5:1/9.0, B|6:1/5.0, B|7:1/5.0]   ['A|14:1/9.0', 'A|15:1/11.0', 'A|16:1/12.0', 'B|11:1/4.0', 'B|2:1/3.0', 'B|3:1/12.0', 'B|4:1/12.0', 'B|5:1/9.0', 'B|6:1/5.0', 'B|7:1/5.0']   ['A|14:1/9.0', 'A|15:1/11.0', 'A|16:1/12.0', 'B|11:1/4.0', 'B|2:1/3.0', 'B|3:1/12.0', 'B|4:1/12.0', 'B|5:1/9.0', 'B|6:1/5.0', 'B|7:1/5.0']  ['A|14:1/9.0', 'A|15:1/11.0', 'A|16:1/12.0', 'B|11:1/4.0', 'B|2:1/4.0', 'B|3:1/12.0', 'B|4:1/12.0', 'B|5:1/9.0', 'B|6:1/6.0', 'B|7:1/5.0']  98          5         
4  709    unit1  2021-08-30  [A|14:1/9.0, A|15:1/11.0, A|16:1/12.0, B|11:1/4.0, B|2:1/3.0, B|3:1/12.0, B|4:1/12.0, B|5:1/9.0, B|6:1/5.0, B|7:1/5.0]   ['A|14:1/9.0', 'A|15:1/11.0', 'A|16:1/12.0', 'B|11:1/4.0', 'B|2:1/3.0', 'B|3:1/12.0', 'B|4:1/12.0', 'B|5:1/9.0', 'B|6:1/5.0', 'B|7:1/5.0']   ['A|14:1/9.0', 'A|15:1/11.0', 'A|16:1/12.0', 'B|11:1/4.0', 'B|2:1/3.0', 'B|3:1/12.0', 'B|4:1/12.0', 'B|5:1/9.0', 'B|6:1/5.0', 'B|7:1/5.0']  ['A|14:1/9.0', 'A|15:1/11.0', 'A|16:1/12.0', 'B|11:1/4.0', 'B|2:1/4.0', 'B|3:1/12.0', 'B|4:1/12.0', 'B|5:1/9.0', 'B|6:1/6.0', 'B|7:1/5.0']  98          6         
5  703    unit1  2021-10-11  [A|14:1/9.0, A|15:1/11.0, A|16:1/12.0, B|11:1/4.0, B|2:1/4.0, B|3:1/12.0, B|4:1/12.0, B|5:1/9.0, B|6:1/6.0, B|7:1/5.0]   ['A|14:1/9.0', 'A|15:1/11.0', 'A|16:1/12.0', 'B|11:1/4.0', 'B|2:1/4.0', 'B|3:1/12.0', 'B|4:1/12.0', 'B|5:1/9.0', 'B|6:1/6.0', 'B|7:1/5.0']   ['A|14:1/9.0', 'A|15:1/11.0', 'A|16:1/12.0', 'B|11:1/4.0', 'B|3:1/12.0', 'B|4:1/12.0', 'B|5:1/9.0', 'B|5:1/8.0', 'B|6:1/5.0', 'B|7:1/5.0']  ['A|14:1/9.0', 'A|15:1/11.0', 'A|16:1/12.0', 'B|11:1/4.0', 'B|3:1/12.0', 'B|4:1/12.0', 'B|5:1/9.0', 'B|5:1/8.0', 'B|6:1/5.0', 'B|7:1/5.0']  100         1         
6  653    unit1  2021-10-18  [A|14:1/9.0, A|15:1/11.0, A|16:1/12.0, B|11:1/4.0, B|2:1/4.0, B|3:1/12.0, B|4:1/12.0, B|5:1/9.0, B|6:1/6.0, B|7:1/5.0]   ['A|14:1/9.0', 'A|15:1/11.0', 'A|16:1/12.0', 'B|11:1/4.0', 'B|2:1/4.0', 'B|3:1/12.0', 'B|4:1/12.0', 'B|5:1/9.0', 'B|6:1/6.0', 'B|7:1/5.0']   ['A|14:1/9.0', 'A|15:1/11.0', 'A|16:1/12.0', 'B|11:1/4.0', 'B|3:1/12.0', 'B|4:1/12.0', 'B|5:1/9.0', 'B|5:1/8.0', 'B|6:1/5.0', 'B|7:1/5.0']  ['A|14:1/9.0', 'A|15:1/11.0', 'A|16:1/12.0', 'B|11:1/4.0', 'B|2:1/3.0', 'B|3:1/12.0', 'B|4:1/12.0', 'B|5:1/9.0', 'B|6:1/5.0', 'B|7:1/5.0']  96          0         
0  1094   unit2  2021-07-26  [A|10:1/7.0, A|12:1/2.0, A|5:1/9.0, A|6:1/11.0, A|6:1/4.0, A|7:1/9.0, A|7:1/4.0, A|8:1/4.0, A|8:1/3.0, A|9:1/2.0]        ['A|10:1/7.0', 'A|12:1/2.0', 'A|5:1/9.0', 'A|6:1/11.0', 'A|6:1/4.0', 'A|7:1/9.0', 'A|7:1/4.0', 'A|8:1/4.0', 'A|8:1/3.0', 'A|9:1/2.0']        ['A|10:1/7.0', 'A|12:1/2.0', 'A|5:1/9.0', 'A|6:1/11.0', 'A|6:1/4.0', 'A|7:1/9.0', 'A|7:1/4.0', 'A|8:1/4.0', 'A|8:1/3.0', 'A|9:1/2.0']       ['A|10:1/7.0', 'A|12:1/2.0', 'A|5:1/9.0', 'A|6:1/11.0', 'A|6:1/4.0', 'A|7:1/9.0', 'A|7:1/4.0', 'A|8:1/4.0', 'A|8:1/3.0', 'A|9:1/2.0']       100         0         
1  1008   unit2  2021-08-09  [A|10:1/7.0, A|12:1/2.0, A|5:1/9.0, A|5:1/4.0, A|6:1/11.0, A|6:1/4.0, A|7:1/9.0, A|7:1/9.0, A|8:1/4.0, A|9:1/2.0]        ['A|10:1/7.0', 'A|12:1/2.0', 'A|5:1/9.0', 'A|5:1/4.0', 'A|6:1/11.0', 'A|6:1/4.0', 'A|7:1/9.0', 'A|7:1/9.0', 'A|8:1/4.0', 'A|9:1/2.0']        ['A|10:1/7.0', 'A|12:1/2.0', 'A|5:1/9.0', 'A|6:1/11.0', 'A|6:1/4.0', 'A|7:1/9.0', 'A|7:1/4.0', 'A|8:1/4.0', 'A|8:1/3.0', 'A|9:1/2.0']       ['A|10:1/7.0', 'A|12:1/2.0', 'A|5:1/9.0', 'A|5:1/4.0', 'A|6:1/11.0', 'A|6:1/4.0', 'A|7:1/9.0', 'A|7:1/9.0', 'A|8:1/4.0', 'A|9:1/2.0']       97          1         
2  1089   unit2  2021-10-04  [A|10:1/7.0, A|12:1/2.0, A|5:1/9.0, A|5:1/2.0, A|6:1/11.0, A|6:1/6.0, A|7:1/9.0, A|7:1/3.0, A|8:1/4.0, A|9:1/2.0]        ['A|10:1/7.0', 'A|12:1/2.0', 'A|5:1/9.0', 'A|5:1/2.0', 'A|6:1/11.0', 'A|6:1/6.0', 'A|7:1/9.0', 'A|7:1/3.0', 'A|8:1/4.0', 'A|9:1/2.0']        ['A|10:1/7.0', 'A|12:1/2.0', 'A|5:1/9.0', 'A|6:1/11.0', 'A|6:1/4.0', 'A|7:1/9.0', 'A|7:1/4.0', 'A|8:1/4.0', 'A|8:1/3.0', 'A|9:1/2.0']       ['A|10:1/7.0', 'A|12:1/2.0', 'A|5:1/9.0', 'A|5:1/2.0', 'A|6:1/11.0', 'A|6:1/6.0', 'A|7:1/9.0', 'A|7:1/3.0', 'A|8:1/4.0', 'A|9:1/2.0']       95          2
```

This method does solve the "comparing the first row with itself" issue, but it does not compare every subsequent row with the first one (for each unit of course!).

Any insights are greatly appreciated.

Comment: do I have this right?  You want to compare each row to the first row for each `unit` value?  Or do you want all pair-wise comparisons within each `unit` value?

Comment: All other rows compared to the first for each unit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to get a similarity measure for each element compared with the first, repeated for each `unit`.  One way to do that:

- *sort by `Date_job` so first row is well defined (not shown)
- create new column `first_vec` that repeats the first `Vector_string` value for each `unit` group
- calculate `fuzz.ratio(Vector_string, first_vec)` for each row
- (clean up temp col `first_vec`)

```py
df["first_vec"] = df.groupby("unit").Vector_string.transform('first')
df["score"] = df.apply(lambda x: fuzz.ratio(x.Vector_string, x.first_vec), axis=1)
df.drop("first_vec", inplace=True)
```

output:

```
       unit    Date_job                                             Vector                                      Vector_string  score
59    unit1  2021-06-07  [A|14:1/9.0, A|15:1/11.0, A|16:1/12.0, B|11:1/...  ['A|14:1/9.0', 'A|15:1/11.0', 'A|16:1/12.0', '...    100
662   unit1  2021-06-14  [A|14:1/9.0, A|15:1/11.0, A|16:1/12.0, B|11:1/...  ['A|14:1/9.0', 'A|15:1/11.0', 'A|16:1/12.0', '...     91
680   unit1  2021-07-05  [A|14:1/9.0, A|14:1/4.0, A|15:1/11.0, A|16:1/1...  ['A|14:1/9.0', 'A|14:1/4.0', 'A|15:1/11.0', 'A...     90
725   unit1  2021-07-26  [A|14:1/9.0, A|15:1/11.0, A|16:1/12.0, B|11:1/...  ['A|14:1/9.0', 'A|15:1/11.0', 'A|16:1/12.0', '...    100
709   unit1  2021-08-30  [A|14:1/9.0, A|15:1/11.0, A|16:1/12.0, B|11:1/...  ['A|14:1/9.0', 'A|15:1/11.0', 'A|16:1/12.0', '...    100
703   unit1  2021-10-11  [A|14:1/9.0, A|15:1/11.0, A|16:1/12.0, B|11:1/...  ['A|14:1/9.0', 'A|15:1/11.0', 'A|16:1/12.0', '...     99
653   unit1  2021-10-18  [A|14:1/9.0, A|15:1/11.0, A|16:1/12.0, B|11:1/...  ['A|14:1/9.0', 'A|15:1/11.0', 'A|16:1/12.0', '...     99
807   unit4  2021-07-19  [A|10:1/13.0, A|10:1/13.0, A|3:1/6.0, A|3:1/6....  ['A|10:1/13.0', 'A|10:1/13.0', 'A|3:1/6.0', 'A...    100
825   unit4  2021-07-26  [A|10:1/13.0, A|10:1/13.0, A|3:1/6.0, A|3:1/6....  ['A|10:1/13.0', 'A|10:1/13.0', 'A|3:1/6.0', 'A...     99
778   unit4  2021-08-23  [A|10:1/13.0, A|10:1/13.0, A|3:1/6.0, A|3:1/6....  ['A|10:1/13.0', 'A|10:1/13.0', 'A|3:1/6.0', 'A...     90
816   unit4  2021-08-30  [A|10:1/13.0, A|10:1/13.0, A|3:1/6.0, A|3:1/6....  ['A|10:1/13.0', 'A|10:1/13.0', 'A|3:1/6.0', 'A...     90
822   unit4  2021-09-06  [A|10:1/13.0, A|10:1/13.0, A|3:1/6.0, A|3:1/6....  ['A|10:1/13.0', 'A|10:1/13.0', 'A|3:1/6.0', 'A...     99
849   unit4  2021-09-27  [A|10:1/13.0, A|10:1/13.0, A|3:1/6.0, A|3:1/6....  ['A|10:1/13.0', 'A|10:1/13.0', 'A|3:1/6.0', 'A...     99
820   unit4  2021-10-04  [A|10:1/13.0, A|10:1/13.0, A|3:1/6.0, A|3:1/6....  ['A|10:1/13.0', 'A|10:1/13.0', 'A|3:1/6.0', 'A...     99
754   unit4  2021-10-18  [A|10:1/13.0, A|10:1/13.0, A|3:1/6.0, A|3:1/6....  ['A|10:1/13.0', 'A|10:1/13.0', 'A|3:1/6.0', 'A...     99
1031  unit3  2021-09-06  [A|10:1/7.0, A|12:1/2.0, A|5:1/10.0, A|5:1/2.0...  ['A|10:1/7.0', 'A|12:1/2.0', 'A|5:1/10.0', 'A|...    100
1094  unit2  2021-07-26  [A|10:1/7.0, A|12:1/2.0, A|5:1/9.0, A|6:1/11.0...  ['A|10:1/7.0', 'A|12:1/2.0', 'A|5:1/9.0', 'A|6...    100
1008  unit2  2021-08-09  [A|10:1/7.0, A|12:1/2.0, A|5:1/9.0, A|5:1/4.0,...  ['A|10:1/7.0', 'A|12:1/2.0', 'A|5:1/9.0', 'A|5...     89
1089  unit2  2021-10-04  [A|10:1/7.0, A|12:1/2.0, A|5:1/9.0, A|5:1/2.0,...  ['A|10:1/7.0', 'A|12:1/2.0', 'A|5:1/9.0', 'A|5...     89
1044  unit5  2021-06-14  [A|10:1/6.0, A|10:1/6.0, A|5:1/4.0, A|5:1/4.0,...  ['A|10:1/6.0', 'A|10:1/6.0', 'A|5:1/4.0', 'A|5...    100
```

You can include the index value of the first row using same tools as above.